# String Format In C# / windows

Tags: c#, string, format, string-formatting

I have a component in my c# application that provide strings like these:

> "2004/1/11"
>
> "2015/12/10"
>
> "1998/1/2"

But i want to change them to these formats:

> "2004/01/11"
>
> "2015/12/10"
>
> "1998/01/02"

Any idea?

Comment: no...component is used in all part of application and i just have to change output....i want to change output string to new format that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
   string InputStr = "2004/1/11";
   String OutputStr = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(InputStr));
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the *strings* in the question are actually *dates*, in that case `DateTime` class is what you're looking for:

```
  String source = "2015/12/10";
  String result = DateTime
   .ParseExact(source, "yyyy/M/d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In case the *strings* are *not dates* (say, some weird codes which look like dates) and you want just *insert zeroes*:

```
  String source = "2015/12/10"; 
  String result = Regex
    .Replace(source, "(?<=/)[0-9](?![0-9])", match => "0" + match.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to convert the strings to dates and back, you could use the [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method. The code could look a little something like this:

`myString = Regex.Replace(myString,@"[^\d](\d)(?=(/|$))","/0$1");`

EDIT: Corrected the pattern.

Comment: Counter example: `myString = "2015/12/1";`; the output is `2015/012/01` when `2015/12/01` expected

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out with your question:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Maybe a timeformat setting will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

its date so you can convert it this way

```
string str = "2004/1/11";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/M/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newstr = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Do not omit `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the `.ToString()` or you can have, say, `2004.01.11` (notice *dots*) since current culture will be used - Russian in the output above

Comment: when parsing *exact* `"yyyy/M/d"` (please, notice one `d` only) is a better pattern than `"yyyy/M/dd"` in a view of `"1998/1/2"` input which will throw a format exception.